# Custom <hr> with image/character in the center

Tags: css, horizontal-line

I'd like to recreate this horizontal rule:

[image]

I have the double lines, but I'm not sure how to go about getting some kind of a character or image in the center. I'm thinking I might be able to use :before and :after, but I don't know how to utilize them in this case. For the sake of answering the question, let's just try and get the center character to be a character. I'll figure out the image/icon later.

Ideas? Here's my code for the lines:

```
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #444;
    border-bottom:1px solid #444;
    margin:25px 0px;
}
```

Comment: I did try using the :before psuedo element a few different ways.  It doesn't look like it can be used to contain information like that glyph.  It seems to act like `overflow: hidden` no matter what, causing the `:before` to be completely hidden unless you give the `hr` a height big enough to show the glyph.

Comment: @cimmanon, check out my answer below. It uses `:after`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of what I was able to produce. See it in action at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/yLKNh/186/).

[image: Screenshot of CSS]

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
  background: #454545;
}

hr {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* choose the font you like */
  text-align: center; /* horizontal centering */
  line-height: 1px; /* vertical centering */
  height: 1px; /* gap between the lines */
  font-size: 1em; /* choose font size you like */
  border-width: 1px 0; /* top and bottom borders */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #676767;
  margin: 20px 10px; /* 20px space above/below, 10px left/right */
  overflow: visible;

  /* ensure 1px gap between borders */
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
  -o-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

hr:after {
  content: "§"; /* section sign */
  color: #999;
  display: inline; /* for vertical centering and background knockout */
  background-color: #454545; /* same as background color */
  padding: 0 0.5em; /* size of background color knockout */
}

/* opera doesn't render correctly. hide section sign */
x:-o-prefocus, hr:after {
  content: "";
}
```

### The section sign

To add the [section sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign), you can use [generated content](http://viget.com/inspire/css-generated-content) with either `:before` or `:after`. The remaining tricky parts are horizontal centering, vertical centering, and knocking out the borders.

### Horizontal centering

Horizontal centering is as simple as adding `text-align: center` to the `hr` and making sure the generated content is `display: inline`.

### Vertical centering

Vertical centering requires a little knowledge of inline rendering. The vertical space consumed by a line of text is determined by `line-height`. Even if the `line-height` is much smaller than the size of the rendered character, the character is still displayed full size, but the space it takes up is dictated by the `line-height`. Using `line-height: 1px` achieves the vertical centering.

### Knocking out the borders

Finally, the only way I know of to knock out the borders behind the section sign is to cover them up with another color. In this case, we use the same background color as is on the rest of the document so it seems to blend in. Set an appropriate `background-color` and then use left and right `padding` to control how much space is to either side of the section sign.

### 1px gap between the borders

You'll also notice that I'm setting `box-sizing: content-box`. This is to ensure that the gap between the borders is 1px. (An alternative but equivalent set up would be `box-sizing: border-box; height: 3px;`.)

### Opera rendering bug

@cimmanon pointed out some Opera rendering bugs, so I decided to degrade gracefully and not show the section sign. I think showing just the lines still looks very tidy and professional. If you really want to get this working in Opera, you could use different markup like `<div class="hr"></div>` (and of course update the CSS to match).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all in Opera.  The `hr` element doesn't allow the before/after pseudo element to overflow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Until a fix is known for this Opera bug, I'm going to degrade gracefully and remove the section sign for Opera.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I believe to be the most responsive, lightweight and modern version for when the symbol isn't a font.

**Snippet**

```css
hr.hr--logo {
  border-top: solid #000 1px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
hr.hr--logo:after {
  content: url( 'logogram.svg' );
  /* Controls the position of the logo */
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  /* Controls the whitespace around the symbol */
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<hr class="hr--logo">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have some css already might aswell give it a background image and a height:

```
hr {
    ... your css ...
    background:url(path to your image) no-repeat center;
    height:15px;
}
```

Comment: This centers the image, but the lines are on the top and bottom of the image. Can I get the image in the center with the double lines centered vertically?

Comment: with my example the bars and the character in between are all part of the image, basically every time you add an hr it displays the whole thing

Comment: So the image would be ===§=== ? How can I get it to fill the width of the container without stretching the §?

Comment: you create a wide image and you make sure § is in the center. remember the image is in the background not an `<img>` tag. So it won't strech

Comment: You can do better than an image. This character exists in Unicode.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesCalo yes the character exist, but using this method makes it much simpler. You simply add an `<hr>` tag and you have a properly centered and formatted divider

Comment: You can still have a simple CSS implementation without the extra HTTP request. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14228760/101869

Answer (score -2):

It's goofy, but you could try to do two half-width HRs with non-breaking space, and the image between them.

```
<hr><img><hr>
```

where there's no spacing or line breaks between the tags.