# An image in the middle of an HR tag

Tags: css

I need something similar to this hr tag

```
hr.style-eight {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: medium double #333;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}
hr.style-eight:after {
    content: "§";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.7em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    background: white;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfweqd7y/)

But I need an image instead of the ASCII symbol. I've tried making the content "" and the background a background-image, but I'm having no luck.

Comment: `content:url(…)` – https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: do you want it all in one `<hr>` tag? because you could try `<hr> <img src="" /> <hr>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom <hr> with image/character in the center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202089/custom-hr-with-image-character-in-the-center)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is an image, not text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than

```
content: '';
```

Use the `url(<url>)` notation:

```
content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUzqW.png);
```

```css
hr.style-eight {
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: medium double #333;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}
hr.style-eight:after {
  content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUzqW.png);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.7em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<hr class="style-eight" />
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gfweqd7y/2/), for experimentation.

References:

- [`content` property (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content#Code_sample_-_content_with_multiple_values).

Comment: You are very correct. I had tried this, but my URL syntax was wrong (using ASP.NET MVC). Once I uploaded that image to imgur and used that URL just to test, I could see that my syntax was off.

Comment: In which case I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Comment: A note regarding this solution, well rather this entire solution, is that Internet Explorer does not support :after css on empty elements. This is causing my centered image to only show up in the other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/gfweqd7y/1/

```
content: url(image.what ever);
```